# Extract IEnumerable out of another IEnumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 classes with the following properties:

OfferList class:

```
Guid Id
IEnumerable<Offer> Offers
```

Offer class:

```
Guid Id
Product Product
```

Product class:

```
Guid Id
```

An OfferList contains multiple Offers and an Offer has exact 1 Product.

How can I get an IEnumerable containing all Products of an OfferList?

```
OfferList offerList = this.GetOfferList(id);
IEnumerable<Product> products = offerList.Offers.SelectMany?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply need to [project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738447.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<Product> products = offerList.Offers.Select(o => o.Product);
```